# Pauses in block environment n LYX (beamer)

Tags: beamer, lyx, overlays

Hey I would like to add pauses into my block environment. For example I have following code:

```
\begin{frame}
We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\left(e^{bt}r\left(t\right)\right)&=&e^{bt}dr\left(t\right)+r\left(t\right)de^{bt}+de^{bt}dr\left(t\right)\\&=&e^{bt}\left[\left(a-br\left(t\right)\right)dt-\sigma dW^{*}\left(t\right)\right]+r\left(t\right)be^{bt}dt\\&=&ae^{bt}dt-\sigma e^{bt}dW^{*}\left(t\right)
\end{eqnarray*},
\end{frame}
```

what do I have to add to my code so that the block is empty at the beginning, then "we" appears and then every lines from eqnarray appears separately? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `eqnarray*` with `align*`. (See also [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/134144)). In order to uncover the individual lines of the `align*` environment, you could use `\onslide`:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
We have 
\pause
\begin{align*}
\onslide<3->{d\left(e^{bt}r\left(t\right)\right)&=e^{bt}dr\left(t\right)+r\left(t\right)de^{bt}+de^{bt}dr\left(t\right)\\}
\onslide<4->{&=e^{bt}\left[\left(a-br\left(t\right)\right)dt-\sigma dW^{*}\left(t\right)\right]+r\left(t\right)be^{bt}dt\\}
\onslide<5->{&=ae^{bt}dt-\sigma e^{bt}dW^{*}\left(t\right)}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```